# List of Existentially Quantified Constructors

Tags: haskell, ghci, monomorphism-restriction

I have the following data type:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

class ToString a where

data M = forall a. (ToString a) => B a
```

In GHCI I can do the following with no problems:

`let bs = [B, B]`

But if I try to do this in a compiled file, I get the following error:

> ```hs
> No instance for (ToString a0) arising from a use of ‘B’
> The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
> Relevant bindings include
>   bs :: [a0 -> M] (bound at src/My/Module:7:1)
> ```

Which extension(s) am I missing that would allow me to create the list of `B` as shown? Or what am I missing that GHCI is adding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because GHCi doesn't turn on the monomorphism restriction, and GHC (by default) does. To witness, the following file typechecks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

class ToString a where

data M = forall a. (ToString a) => B a

bs = [B, B]
```

The inferred type of `bs` is fairly useless, of course:

```
*Main> :t bs
bs :: ToString a => [a -> M]
```

If you don't want to turn off the monomorphism restriction, you can just add a type signature to the definition of `bs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class ToString a where

data M = forall a. (ToString a) => B a

bs :: (ToString a) => [a -> M]
bs = [B, B]
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Knowing all of these GHC language extensions is an art in an of itself :-)

Comment: @kurzweil4: now imagine using another (proprietary) Haskell compiler, with its own quirks, for your day job...

Comment: I wish GHC would just say "OK, we are Haskell" and get it over with. Then they can just add as many features as they want and not be limited by some old standard. Then, they can publish the spec of "GHC Haskell" as THE Haskell, and if someone else wants to make a compiler, just follow their spec. As far as I know, they are the only (significant) game in town. Perhaps that could get rid of the need for all these language pragmas?

Comment: @Cactus, I didn't know there *was* a proprietary Haskell compiler. What's that like?

Comment: @dfeuer: http://anil.recoil.org/papers/2011-cufp-scribe-preprint.pdf spoiler alert: it's Mu

Comment: @dfeuer: also: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/35042c/mirror_for_don_stewarts_google_talk/

Comment: I realize deciding which ones should be included would be contentious, but it would be nice if you could simply say `{-# LANGUAGE GhcAll -#}` and get all the extensions at once. There must be *some* fairly large subset of extensions that would cover most uses with a minimal compile- or run-time impact.

Comment: @chepner, well, there's `-fglasgow-exts`, but that's deprecated because it means entirely different things in different versions and doesn't make it the least bit clear what the module actually needs.